# Run liquibase rollback without changelog files?

Tags: liquibase

Liquibase is not able to rollback a without the changelog files.
It requires to provide the original changelogs/changesets files when running a rollback.

My questions is: Is there any way to run rollback without the files?

E.g.: Store the files (or rollback commands) in the databasechangelog table?

Answer (score 1):

You could use Liquibase's "Future Rollback SQL" feature. It's exposed in several different ways.

[Java API](http://www.liquibase.org/javadoc/liquibase/Liquibase.html)

```
Liquibase.futureRollbackSQL(...)
```

[Spring Integration](http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/spring.html)

```
SpringLiquibase.setRollbackFile(...)
```

[Maven Integration](http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/maven/maven_futurerollbacksql.html)

```
 mvn liquibase:futureRollbackSQL
```

[Ant Integration](http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/ant/rollbackfuturedatabase_ant_task.html)

```
<liquibase:rollbackFutureDatabase outputfile="/path/to/rollback-future.sql".../>
```

[Command Line](http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/command_line.html)

```
liquibase futureRollbackSQL
```

If you use this feature in conjunction with update or updateSQL then you will be able to rollback the update without the original change logs.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know liquibase generates the rollback commands on the fly from the changesets (in those cases where this is possible).

So it will always need the changelog files to do this.

I dont't think that there is an easy solution to do this. The whole point of liquibase is to keep the changesets in separate files, so you can put them in some sort of version control system.